# How do you create left sidebar with comment count, Facebook like count and other social media popularity stats?

Tags: wordpress, facebook, facebook-like

Over the last year, I noticed that lots of sites have moved their share/popularity stats to a left sidebar that remains visible on the screen even if you scroll the window down.  Here is the URL for a page that has this kind of functionality: http://news.cnet.com/8301-31921_3-57371426-281/anti-sopa-forces-have-isp-snooping-bill-in-their-crosshairs

What's the best way to create that kind of sidebar?

Answer (score 0):

an easy way is to use CSS to absolutely position it and set the Z index so that it appears above everything else

Answer (score 0):

try this on your HTML page

```
<style>
.side-sharebar {
    display: block;
    left: 482px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 20px;
    -moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
    -moz-border-image: none;
    -moz-border-left-colors: none;
    -moz-border-right-colors: none;
    -moz-border-top-colors: none;
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    border-color: #CCCCCC transparent #CCCCCC #CCCCCC;
    border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    box-shadow: -6px 0 6px -6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) inset, 0 1px 0 #FFFFFF inset;
    left: auto !important;
    margin-left: -98px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 76px;
}

.side-sharebar ul li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #FFFFFF;
    padding: 10px 2px 10px 0;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

.side-sharebar ul {
    list-style: none outside none;
}
</style>
....
<div class="side-sharebar"><ul><li>one</li><li>two</li></ul></div>
```